# Cancel Copy Operation on java

Tags: java, io, apache-commons, fileutils

I'm using Apache commons IO for copying files and Directories and I need to add cancel feature. Cancelling the copying operation should leave the files copied as they are till the button is clicked.

The following code is used for copying:
    **FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);**

Is there any idea to cancel this operation or i need to change copying code for adding cancelling feature??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) This is not even a question... [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: For canceling I havent got an idea.. So i need some ideas to solve that.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commons-io makes no provision for callbacks for a cancel/pause/restart.

Since it is open source, you can start from the source and implement what you need.